# Visual Studio does not load my DLL from the correct folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have just realized that my ASP.NET application seems to be somehow mis-setupped.
For any reason, when I build it, the dll file is correctly generated into the /bin/debug folder.

However, for any reason, there is a MyApp.dll file into /bin folder and this is the one that the application seems to load.

I mean that:
 - if I remove the /bin/debug/MyApp.dll and leave the /bin/MyApp.dll : it works fine
 - if I leavethe /bin/debug/MyApp.dll and remove the /bin/MyApp.dll : it works fine : I get a server application error (impossible to load MyDomain.Default).

How can I setup this back to normal???

EDIT:
Into the project properties/build: output path is correctly setupped as bin\Debug\

Comment: Can you provide exact exception? Also, see inner exception, maybe your dll framework is not the same as your using project.

Comment: error is :
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyDomain.Default'.


But I don't think it is relevant as it only means that VS attempted to load from a file that does not exist

Comment: Look at your reference list to see where is loading it from. If in doubt, delete the reference and add a new one pointing the path of the one you want to use

Comment: @ Pikoh in this case, the project having the issue is the solution starting project.
So the concerned project is not referenced into its own reference folder. Right?

Comment: No,not right. I don't understand but it may be me :) Anyway, a map of your solution may be helpful in order to help

Comment: @ Pikoh: I mean, let's say that your solution contains a single project named MyProject having the issue that I described .MyProject will not appear into MyProject's references : a project does not reference itself AFAIK.

Comment: Of course a project can't reference itself. But then, i really don't understand your problem. Maybe someone smarter than me would help :)

Comment: Thx anyway for your time :)